# vue.js bootstrap-vue dynamically change alert variant

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

So I'm using bootstrap-vue in a vue.js project, and this is the way you can display an alert acording to the docs:

```
<b-alert variant="success" show>Success Alert</b-alert>
```

What I'm trying to do is

```
<b-alert variant=alertvariant show>Success Alert</b-alert>

//...

<script>
export default {
    name: 'SetPOS',
    data() {
        return {                       
            alertvariant: "warning"
        }
    },
...
```

But this is not working, the alert is showing up withouth style. Is there any way I can use variables in the variant property of the alert, so I can dynamically change it from code??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to bind the `alertvariant` prop to `variant` attribute like this:

```
<b-alert :variant="alertvariant" show>Success Alert</b-alert>
```

Note `:variant` is a shortcut for `v-bind:variant`

More info on data binding [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering)

Comment: and can we use a function to check the value and decide which variant to use?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It seems v-bind is not implemented for the variant property https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/alert#comp-ref-b-alert-props

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
<b-button :variant="foo" @click="dataName = !dataName">Button Name</b-button>

//...

<script>
export default {
    name: 'componentName',
    data() {
        return {                       
            dataName: true //<--- define data
        }
    },
computed: {
    foo() {
      return this.dataName ? "success" : "warning"; //<--- define condition/s
    }
}
...
```